# Why is the inner product on L2 defined as an expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

The book on probability theory I'm reading defines the inner product of $X, Y \in \mathcal{L}^2$ as $\langle X, Y \rangle = E(XY)$. I would like to understand why the inner product is defined as such.

Comment: You define it this way because it is very useful. There are other ways of defining inner products, of course.

Comment: Could you point to one of these other ways of defining the inner product, for $\mathcal{L}^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $L^2$ is a normed vector space for the norm $$\Vert X\Vert_2 = \mathbb E[X^2]^{1/2}$$ Now ideally, an inner product on $L^2$ would be compatible with the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ meaning $$\langle X,X\rangle = \Vert X\Vert_2^2$$(think of the euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^d$ and the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^d$ for a clearer example of this concept)

This is exactly the case if we define $$\langle X,Y\rangle:= \mathbb E[X\cdot Y]$$
This makes $L^2$ into an inner product space, specifically (after some modification) into a Hilbert space. This is a very nice property that is somewhat exclusive to $L^2$.

Comment: Then, the inner product is defined as such because we want L2 to have the 2-norm? Does this mean that the norm is induced by the inner product in this case? And, what do you mean by 'somewhat exclusive to $\mathcal{L}^2$? Thanks, and apologies for my lack of mathematical understanding.

Comment: @antarctica Yes, $L_2$ has norm $\mathbb E X^2$. The chosen inner product induces this norm. This property is special to $L_2$ in the sense that for any $L_p$ with $p\neq 2$, $L_p$ is not a Hilbert space, meaning there's no inner product inducing the $p$-norm $\mathbb  E |X|^p$.